# What is the name of this "yawning like" movement?

Tags: single-word-requests, image-identification

You may do this when you're tired or after a nap. This movement is usually called "yawning" but I think yawning is a bit different. With this movement, we may yawn too. After waking up, it usually comes with a yawning but when we are tired, we usually don't yawn with. And this movement makes us feel better.

The picture below is an example of this movement:

[image]

The picture's source: [nordic-comfort.co.uk](http://nordic-comfort.co.uk)

In some languages, like Persian (aka Farsi), there is no difference between yawning and this movement but in some other languages like Azerbaijani, there is a difference.

Comment: That woman is *stretching*.

Comment: @DanBron In reality, that woman is *posing*, but that's getting away from the point of the image...

Comment: Interesting question. I think if the OP was looking for the word _stretching_, ELL would have been the better place to ask. If the OP was really fishing for _pandiculation_, then ELU is the right place. Just another example of how the dividing line is more about the answer sought than the question asked. (To the O.P.: you probably don't want to start saying, "After yesterday's workout, it felt so good to pandiculate this morning" – at least, not in casual conversation.)

Comment: But in Farsi we don't call both of them " yawning"! We call this one " كش و قوس دادن"! , @Amirreza Nasiri.

Comment: @Soudabeh You right but it's like stretching in English. We may use it for other purposes. In Azerbaijani language for example, we use "گَرنَشماخ" specially for this.

Comment: Sorry@Amirreza Nadiri. , I though you are Iraninan. :)

Comment: @Soudabeh of course I am :)

Comment: I think you may be misunderstanding what _yawning_ is. To yawn is to involuntarily open your mouth wide and take a very deep breath. Most people yawn both when they are tired at night and when they wake up in the morning. You can yawn without stretching, and you can stretch without yawning, but it is very common to yawn when you stretch, regardless of what time of day it is.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

There is a specific name for it: ***pandiculation***.

> A stretching and stiffening of the trunk and extremities, as when fatigued and drowsy or on waking, often accompanied by yawning.
>
> http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pandiculation

[image]

<sub>Joseph Ducreux pandiculating; self-portrait ca 1783</sub>

Note: While *stretching* is more common, it is also more general. OP didn't specifically asked for a common word and there are details in the question. *Pandiculation* is a tailor-made word for this specific movement. At least, you learned a new word if you didn't know it.

Comment: I challenge you to look at that painting and not yawn. Just saying.

Comment: THIS is the correct answer.  +1.  Nice job truly understanding the question.

Comment: Wow! thank you. This is what I wanted. it's wired that there is no translation for this noun in several languages. but why pandiculation are shown incorrect noun in browser's text field and word processor programs?

Comment: @AmirrezaNasiri: You can find it on many online dictionaries: [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/medical/pandiculation?show=0&t=1416887497), [Vocabulary](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/pandiculation), [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/pandiculation) etc.

Comment: @Ermanen last question. is this noun a 'common' one? I mean, is it friendly word against 'stretching'? which one people use often?

Comment: That portrait needs to be a meme.

Comment: @AmirrezaNasiri It's not a common word. I'm a native English speaker and I don't think I've ever come across this word before. Google Ngrams suggests it's about 1/1000 times as common in books as 'yawn': https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pandiculation%2C+yawn&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpandiculation%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cyawn%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @bdsl - I can't believe it's actually that common!  (And I think I liked the first picture better.)

Comment: @AmirrezaNasiri No, it is certainly not a common term. If you posted you picture and the one above, almost everyone would say they are stretching. Also, if you are really trying to get a good handle on less academic English usage, you should visit Stack's English Language Learners beta site.

Comment: @AmirrezaNasiri: Sorry, I had to delete my comment before, because of a discussion. Yes, it is not a common word as a lot of people already mentioned. In everyday speech, you would use "stretching" but stretching is a general word also. You can also do stretching before exercising or any time. You asked the name of a specific movement (or we might call it a specific type of stretching) in detail. I would also think that you knew the word "stretching" because it is a basic term and you asked this question on ELU (which is a more advanced-level site than [ELL](http://ell.stackexchange.com/))

Comment: This is the first and probably the last time that I have read (or heard) the word "pandiculation". Whereas the answer is technically correct, it might be misleading if the OP wants to put this in a sentence. The OED states: ***Medicine. Now rare.* The act of stretching (extending the limbs and neck), as a manifestation of weariness, a sign of disease, etc. In later use also: yawning (rare).** I would suggest that it is so rare that it should not be used.

Answer (score 44):

She is doing the same thing this cat is doing: *stretching.*

[image]

English doesn't have a common word for the stretching associated with yawning, or with waking up. Do it whenever you need to, just because it feels good.

Comment: While "pandiculation" may be a technically correct term, the likelihood that any audience will understand you when you say it is extremely low. This is the answer if you want people to understand you. You might pair it like "Yawn and stretch" to ensure the full understanding.

Answer (score 1):

### [Rax](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rax)

> (Britain, dialectal, chiefly Scotland, intransitive) To stretch after sleep.

Comment: I’ve never heard this before, but it’s a lovely wee word – immediately adding to my vocabulary of words to use whenever I’m in the northern parts of Britain!

Answer (score -1):

To "stretch" or to "stretch oneself" is by far the commonest usage for the concept. It means to thrust out one's limbs and tighten one's muscles after being relaxed. "To pandiculate" is, as I have looked, a physiological term, though it may well be used in a formal tone. A bonus expression that does not bear upon the case in point is "to stretch one's legs", which means to exercise oneself by walking. Care must be taken not to mix up "stretch oneself" and "stretch one's legs" by taking one for the other.

Comment: The woman in photo is "stretching". To "stretch oneself" is to choose to perform tasks that one finds challenging, e.g., as training or practice.  (For example, "The best student stretched himself by attempting the most difficult problems in the textbook.")